# Is there a way to make a fey or outsider eligible for the Eidolon Ghost class?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, races

In *Ghostwalk* it says that humanoid souls are able to resist the pull of the "True Afterlife" and return to the material plane. These souls become ghosts and are forced to take the Eidolon class. Is there any way for a fey or outsider to become eligible for this mechanic? I'm running a *Ghostwalk*-based game and I want my players to have a larger choice of races than just humanoids.

Answer (score 5):

If it's your game, simply say that all souls, not just humanoid ones, can resist the pull.  You're the GM, you can ignore or change any rule that you want.  Trying to find a RAW solution when a rule change is much easier is often less effective.

If you're looking for a RAW way to make it work, there's no way that I know of to make a fey or outsider into a humanoid.

Comment: But but the WotC game police might come by and declare your game non-sanctioned!  Then where would you be?

Comment: it would make sense to me if native outsiders might be able to because they can be ressed normally. however i cannot think of any way for fey to work.

Comment: i could also suppose what if my players die then if they arent ghostable they just die and have to deal with it. i have been known to be a heartless bastard.

Comment: is there a half fey or somthing like that?

Comment: Not that I am aware of.  Native outsiders likely should be considered as Humanoid for Ghostwalk, since Ghostwalk was written before Native Outsider was a thing, IIRC.  Honestly, though, just houserule it.  Maybe fey can ghost themselves because they have an intimate connection to the world, and so can resist the afterlife better.  Maybe outsiders can use their extraplanar nature to resist the pull of an earthly death.  Whatever makes the most sense to you and your group.